# Exportar Datatable con los datos Modificados

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, datatable

tengo un problema al exportar datatable, he logrado modificar los valores en mi table, pero al exportar solo se exportan como si no lo estuviesen... detallo.

En primer lugar este es mi codigo:

```
 var table = $('#relation-table').DataTable({
    dom: 'lBfrtip',
    "lengthMenu": [ [15, 25, 50, -1], [15, 25, 50, "All"] ],
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ],
    'rowCallback': function(row, data, index){
        for (let i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
            if(data[i]==1){
                $('td', row).eq(i).html('A');
                $('td', row).eq(i).css('color', 'green');
                $('td', row).eq(i).css("background-color", "rgb(193, 255, 194)");
                }
            else if(data[i]==2){
                $('td', row).eq(i).text('T');
                $('td', row).eq(i).css('color', 'brown');
                $('td', row).eq(i).css("background-color", "rgb(255, 252, 193)");
            }else if(data[i]==3){
                $('td', row).eq(i).text('F')
                $('td', row).eq(i).css('color', 'red');
                $('td', row).eq(i).css("background-color", "rgb(255, 193, 208)");
            }else if(data[i]==4){
                $('td', row).eq(i).text('P');
                $('td', row).eq(i).css('color', 'blue');
                $('td', row).eq(i).css("background-color", "rgb(194, 238, 252)");
            }else if(data[i]==5){
                $('td', row).eq(i).text('D')
                $('td', row).eq(i).css('color', 'red');
                $('td', row).eq(i).css("background-color", "rgb(226, 194, 252)");
            } else{
                $('td', row).eq(i).text('-')
                }
        }
    }
});
```

De lo cual, me muestra lo siguiente :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual es perfecto, y todo bien por ahi... hasta que lo exporto a excel o a PDF... me lo muestra de la siguiente manera .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay manera que lo muestre como en la tabla.